# Redirect traffic of Azure Application Gateway based on health probe

Tags: azure-application-gateway

Can an Azure Application Gateway be configured to re-direct traffic to another URL, when its health prob return 4xx or 5xx errors?

Suppose one of the services in the backend pool of the App Gateway is down and therefore the AppGateway's health-prob gets a response showing it is unhealthy. Can the traffic coming through the App Gateway be automatically redirected to another URL based on the health probe response?

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior.

> Azure Application Gateway by default monitors the health of all resources in its backend pool and automatically removes any resource considered unhealthy from the pool. Application Gateway continues to monitor the unhealthy instances and adds them back to the healthy backend pool once they become available and respond to health probes. By default, Application gateway sends the health probes with the same port that is defined in the backend HTTP settings. A custom probe port can be configured using a custom health probe.

and

> In addition to using default health probe monitoring, you can also customize the health probe to suit your application's requirements.

Source: [Application Gateway health monitoring overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-probe-overview)